# Single click does not play html5 audio

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using multiple audio files in a sample page for that I have added few JS which is making my audio not to play on first click.

The code is basically for the audio to work both on Play button click as well image click, but unfortunately the image works fine but the button is not working on a single click

```js
document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
        if(audios[i] != e.target){
            audios[i].pause();
        }
    }
}, true);

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var songlist = $('.medical-minutes-list li');
  $(songlist).each(function(){
  var getAudioLink = $(this).find('a');
        
  $(getAudioLink[0]).click(function(){  
           
    //pause playing other audio
   $('audio').trigger('paused');
   
    //set play time to 0  for other audio
    //$('audio').prop('currentTime',0);
    if($(this).find('.overlay2').hasClass("overLi"))
    { 
           $('audio').trigger('pause');
   $(this).find('.overlay audio').trigger('pause');    
           $('.overlay2').removeClass('overLi'); 
    }
    else
    {
           $('audio').trigger('pause');
           $('.overlay2').removeClass('overLi');
    //starts playing current audio 
    $(this).find('.overlay audio').trigger('play');
    $(this).find('.overlay2').addClass('overLi');
    }
          
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.medical-minutes-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.medical-minutes-list li {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul li {
    padding: 4px 0 4px 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.medical-minutes-list li a {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 173px;
}
li{list-style-type:none}
.medical-minutes-list li a img {
    width: 100%;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.medical-minutes-list .audio {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #868686;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f1f3f4;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 56px!important;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.innerLeftContent .minutes .medical-minutes-list li a .overLi, .innerLeftContent .minutes .medical-minutes-list li a:hover .overlay {
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3803921568627451);
    background-position: center;
}
.innerLeftContent .minutes .medical-minutes-list li a .overLi, .innerLeftContent .minutes .medical-minutes-list li a:hover .overlay {
    display: block!important;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(http://wphredesign.stage.bluespiremarketing.net/WPHRedesign/media/Emerge_WPHRedesign/Audio/mic.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 96px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: auto!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="minutes">
<ul class="medical-minutes-list">
<li><a><img src="http://coffeeandcotton.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MUSIC.jpg"> <span class="overlay2 overLi"> </span> <span class="overlay overlay1">
  <audio class="audio" controls="" src="http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/rain.mp3">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
  </span> </a>
  <div class="details">
 <h4><strong>demo</strong></h4>
  </div>
</li><li><a><img src="http://coffeeandcotton.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MUSIC.jpg"> <span class="overlay2"> </span> <span class="overlay overlay1">
  <audio class="audio" controls="" src="http://www.evidenceaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/monsterchords.mp3">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
  </span> </a>
  <div class="details">
 <h4><strong>demo</strong></h4>
  </div>
</li><li><a><img src="http://coffeeandcotton.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MUSIC.jpg"> <span class="overlay2"> </span> <span class="overlay overlay1">
  <audio class="audio" controls="" src="http://www.evidenceaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/lyricslap.mp3">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
  </span> </a>
  <div class="details">
 <h4><strong>demo</strong></h4>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're redundantly pausing every audio element 3-4 different times before any of them play:
   - In the event listener on the entire page if it's not the clicked/playing element
   - On every single `audio` element any time the 1st link on the page is clicked
   - Every time the element with class `overlay2` also has class `overLi`, and also when it does not (which is always). Was going to break it down to simplify, but the answer below already does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from your question that you simply want to be able to play the `audio` element by clicking the play button in the controls or the related `img` element, and when that happens all other audio should stop.

If that's the case your code is much more complicated than it needs to be. The multitude of event handlers is causing your problem.

To fix this you can simply attach a `click` handler to the `img` to stop/start the audio, and an `play` handler on the audio themselves to stop the others from playing.

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.medical-minutes-list a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $audio = $(this).find('audio');
    $audio.data('playing') ? $audio.trigger('pause') : $audio.trigger('play');
  });

  $('.audio').on('play', function() {
    $('.audio').data('playing', true).not(this).trigger('pause').data('playing', false);
  }).on('pause', function() {
    $(this).data('playing', false);
  });
});
```

```css
.medical-minutes-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.medical-minutes-list li {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 4px 0 4px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.medical-minutes-list li a {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 173px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none
}

.medical-minutes-list li a img {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.medical-minutes-list .audio {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #868686;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f1f3f4;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 56px!important;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.innerLeftContent .minutes .medical-minutes-list li a .overLi,
.innerLeftContent .minutes .medical-minutes-list li a:hover .overlay {
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3803921568627451);
  background-position: center;
}

.innerLeftContent .minutes .medical-minutes-list li a .overLi,
.innerLeftContent .minutes .medical-minutes-list li a:hover .overlay {
  display: block!important;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(http://wphredesign.stage.bluespiremarketing.net/WPHRedesign/media/Emerge_WPHRedesign/Audio/mic.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 96px;
  left: 30px;
  right: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: auto!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="minutes">
  <ul class="medical-minutes-list">
    <li>
      <a>
        <img src="http://coffeeandcotton.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MUSIC.jpg">
        <span class="overlay2 overLi"> </span>
        <span class="overlay overlay1">
          <audio class="audio" controls="" src="http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/rain.mp3">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
        </span>
      </a>
      <div class="details">
        <h4><strong>demo</strong></h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <img src="http://coffeeandcotton.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MUSIC.jpg"> 
        <span class="overlay2"></span> 
        <span class="overlay overlay1">
          <audio class="audio" controls="" src="http://www.evidenceaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/monsterchords.mp3">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
        </span>
      </a>
      <div class="details">
        <h4><strong>demo</strong></h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <img src="http://coffeeandcotton.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/MUSIC.jpg"> 
        <span class="overlay2"></span> 
        <span class="overlay overlay1">
          <audio class="audio" controls="" src="http://www.evidenceaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/lyricslap.mp3">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
        </span>
      </a>
      <div class="details">
        <h4><strong>demo</strong></h4>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would also strongly suggest you remove the `<a>` elements. They are intended to be used as anchors to other content in your site, not to group elements.

Comment: Thank you very much brother!! 

But the audio is not playing when i click second time.. 

And also I'm adding an "overLi" class for hover effect when playing an audio and removing it when other audio is been played

Comment: The audio seems to work fine in the snippet above, so I cannot help with an issue which I can't reproduce. I'd suggest starting a new question if you have issues with your implementation. You can easily add/remove the class on the audio elements in the `play` event handler.

Comment: Hi Sorry If you didn't get my query, play the same audio for second time without going to next one.. its not working.. I'm trying on Chrome browser and Safari

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. It's because the `data` attribute wasn't being reset when pausing the audio. I added another `pause` event handle to fix it

Comment: Thanks bro, its working perfect .. U saved my Job :)

Comment: Hi @Rory McCrossan  https://jsfiddle.net/g8rxp3h0/36/
I modified d code little to show a Mic image while playing, but it works good while clicking the background image and not working while clicking Audio Player's Play button, this is only on Firefox and IE, but works great on Chrome 

can u pls help me on this

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really able to help at the moment. I'd suggest starting a new question about that, making sure to include all relevant details